Accessing/reading Xamarin.Android old (other) app settings (shared_prefs)
I would like to read some user settings from the old (another package name) Xamarin.Android app in my new MAUI app.
In my old application, I used to save settings by calling the method
PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.Context)

In the new MAUI application I tried using a new context (based on old packageName) to read the old preferences file; the name of the resource that should be read is correct, but the settings list is always empty.
By the way, here the code I used to experiment:
var oldContext = Application.Context.CreatePackageContext(packageName, PackageContextFlags.IgnoreSecurity); 
var settingsList = oldContext.GetSharedPreferences(oldContext.PackageName + "_preferences", FileCreationMode.Private);

Any ideas/suggestion to solve this problem?

In Maui, have you tried to use Preferences to store and get the app settings?

@Alexander May Mmmm...yes, but it's seems to work just for new MAUI app. Well, I should access the settings of the old app made with Xamarin.Android. Can Maui Preferences class access old ‘_preferences’ files in another context (different file system)?

By default, you can't use GetSharedPreferences to read the settings of another app. For more details, you can refer to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.
